# I am trying to draw shapes using mouse events in jcanvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, jcanvas

I am trying to draw shapes on canvas using mouse events in JCanvas. I am trying to implement it by creating a temporary canvas to draw shapes. My question here is can we implement temporary canvas in JCanvas?
I am not getting any idea of how to draw shapes on canvas in JCanvas using mouseevents.
Can you please give a basic example of using mouse events to draw shapes in jcanvas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hope this helps http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/docs/mouseEvents/

Comment: check this http://www.codicode.com/art/how_to_draw_on_a_html5_canvas_with_a_mouse.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to copy what is being done here:

http://calebevans.me/projects/painter/

They use this script to draw:

```
(function (e) {
    e.fn.brushTool = function () {
        function i() {
            e.drawArc({
                fillStyle: color,
                x: n,
                y: r,
                radius: stroke / 2
            })
        }
        var e = this;
        e.unbind();
        var t = !1,
            n, r;
        e.on(getTouchEventName("mousedown"), function (s) {
            hist.push(last.src = e[0].toDataURL("image/png"));
            t = !0;
            n = s.offsetX;
            r = s.offsetY;
            i();
            return !1
        });
        e.on(getTouchEventName("mouseup"), function () {
            t = !1
        });
        e.on(getTouchEventName("mousemove"), function (e) {
            if (t === !0) {
                n = e.offsetX;
                r = e.offsetY;
                i()
            }
        })
    }
})(jQuery);
```